# A correct way to store html page in a PHP variable, parse and show it

Tags: javascript, php, html, simple-html-dom

Actually am using simple_html_dom parser to parse a html page. Then did some modifications. And now want to show that in my page.

```
$page = file_get_html($url);
foreach($page->find('div#someDIv') as $e) {
    $e->style = 'display:none;';
}

foreach($page->find('td#Something') as $e) {
    $e->style = 'display:none;';
}
foreach($page->find('td#Something2') as $e) {
    $e->style = 'display:none;';
}

$page->save();

?>
```

Now I echo and show it,

```
<?php echo $page; ?>
```

The content is displayed properly but I see some java script errors which is preventing my remaining script to execute.

The errors I see are

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

these error are on the line where i `echo $page`

Is there a better way to show the content so these errors can be prevented and the javascript below it can be executed.

**UPDATE:**
I see the error here,
[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You should show the rendered output (at the very least, the part causing the error)

Comment: note that if you retreive html elements with scripts inside, they logically might throw errors for various reasons, like vars not defined, missing frameworks, missing html elements, etc. Depending on the case, you could simply remove script tags

Comment: @PatrickQ  updated with error part.

Comment: @PatrickQ there the `;` is ending the line. How to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has own class to work with HTML dom, called [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php).
Your example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

To find dom element use [XPath](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php)

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("*/td[@id='Something']");
if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
     $element.setAttribute('style','display: none;');
  }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Could this be use to save embeded codes such as youtube? Sorry for hijack this, but I need to save and show codes, but I'm afraid javascript's could be inserted or some other thing.

Comment: This code make valid HTML,  if the page contains the scripts that include from server you will get errors like : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, Uncaught SyntaxError: What u need with embedded video?